# Natural Earth Data and OSM do not overlap

Tags: openstreetmap, scale, natural-earth

I downloaded data from [natural earth data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/). The data are all the admin areas in the world 1:10m. I overlay this data with OpenStreetMap, and there are parts where the natural earth data really is off. I would not expect to match the natural earth data every curve of the underlying OpenStreetMap tiles. But at least I expect a correct positioning of the lines. Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem? Could that be a projection problem? The natural earth data is projected in EPSG:4326. The QGIS project is also set to this projection...

[image: Bangladesh]

[image: Eastern Europe]

On other places, it fits quite reasonable.

[image]

Or, is this just the data. If that is the case, does anyone know a simplified world country file, yet where the border lines are more accurate positioned?

Comment: "The carefully generalized linework maintains consistent, recognizable geographic shapes at 1:10m, 1:50m, and 1:110m scales. " so vertices have been removed. so your comparing 2 different datasets at different captured scales.

Comment: @Mapperz this would explain the simplification of the lines, but not the displacement?!

Comment: There are many types of generalization in GIS/Cartography including smooth that can be applied https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartographic_generalization

Comment: Re the displacement, I'd try and feed back the problem to  one or other of Natural Earth or OSM (whichever one you suspect is wrong).  Certainly from the OSM side it'd be straightforward to track down how a bit of boundary came to be in a particular place; I suspect it'd be true for Natural Earth also.

Comment: A person with one GIS boundary file knows where the boundary is. A person with two GIS boundary files is never sure...

Answer (score 0):

There is this tool https://osm-boundaries.com/. Using it, one can extract the boundaries from the OSM data pretty easily here. To reduce size, one can use this tool https://mapshaper.org/ and play a little bit around with the algorithms provided.